# swift 3 tableview crash

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview

I'm now shifting to swift 3 and I faced a problem with the tableViews when I create a table view (in a viewController) and connect to to a class I get this error :

```
-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-gdE-bi-3N4" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView
```

I don't know what is the problem and it's driving me crazy , here is my code :

```
    import UIKit

class FindFriendVC: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var results: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.results.dataSource = self
        self.results.delegate = self
    }



    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: check if `results` IBOutlet is properly connected. It seems results is connected to something which isn't `UITableView`

Comment: @no one In your storyboard, you need to make the root view of your UITableViewController a UITableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you create an extra `UITableView` `IBOutlet`?

Every `UITableViewController` has an implicit property `tableView` with pre-connected `DataSource` and `Delegate`.

Delete

```
@IBOutlet weak var results: UITableView!
...
self.results.dataSource = self
self.results.delegate = self
```

and use the `tableView` property.

Comment: I am using a regular view controller that's why I need to connect the tableView

Comment: Then your code is confusing. It's definitely a subclass of *UI**Table**ViewController*.

Comment: @no one can you be more clear what all steps have you done?

Comment: @vadian sorry I identified the problem , when I switched to swift 3 I misunderstood the docs XD , I really need some sleep ! , anyway I solved the problem I was stupid ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need the IBOutlet in the Tableview controller - that is something you just need if you're using a regular ViewController with UITableView delegates to control the table.

Edit: What I usually do is add a UITableView to a regular ViewController in the builder, right click drag from the tableview to the ViewController icon (yellow circle with white square)

[image]

and connect the delegate & datasource. Then add the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource classes to the view controller & hook up the tableView numberOfSections & numberOfRowsInSection like you have above, except putting all the code in the viewController class, not the UITAbleViewController class.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am using a regular view controller that's why I need to connect the tableView

Comment: sorry I identified the problem , when I switched to swift 3 I misunderstood the docs XD , I really need some sleep ! , anyway I solved the problem I was stupid ! thanks